# From two array list to model class c#

Tags: c#

I have two array list

1. Ids
2. names

and i want store values in model class(ModelClas) object
List obj = new List();?

```
 public class ModelClas
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Names { get; set; }
 }
 string[] Ids = StudentId.Split(',');
 string[] names = FieldName.Split(',');
 List<ModelClas> obj = new List<ModelClas>();
```

Comment: What is `obj`? What did you expect, exactly? Were you able to observe any details about how it worked instead? If you were able to observe any program behavior, error messages, etc., please edit your question and add that information. Thanks!

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working as expected".  What problem are you observing?

Comment: List<ModelClas> obj = new List<ModelClas>();
in this list of obj i want to add data

Comment: @AkshayRasalkar If you're unwilling or unable to describe what went wrong, we won't be able to help you.

Comment: post an example of StudentID and FieldName, maybe the split is failing.  Check the length of Ids and names and that should give you a hint.

Comment: i have updated my question

Comment: StudentID and FieldName these are values stored in arrays

Answer (score 2):

Try to `Zip` both arrays with a help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  List<ModelClas> obj = Ids
    .Zip(names, (id, name) => new ModelClas() {
       Id = id, 
       Names = name
      })
    .ToList();
```

In case of no Linq solution, you can change `foreach` loops into `for` one:

```
  List<ModelClas> obj = new List<ModelClas>();

  // Math.Min - to be on the safe side if the arrays are of different lengths 
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(Ids.Length, names.Length); ++i) {
    // i-th Ids and names into ModelClas   
    obj.Add(new ModelClas() {
      Id = Ids[i],
      Names = names[i] 
    }); 
  }
```

Comment: That'll clearly produce the desired result, but I wonder if OP will understand it.